# Estoy agregando color a un dataframe con np.select y pd.style.apply pero me sale un error

Tags: python, pandas, style

Muy buenas, estoy realizando un script que me permita agregar color a unas casillas de unas filas que cumplan con dos condiciones y para ello uso una función y pd.style.apply este es el codigo de la funcion:

```
def funciomAgregarColores(column, bool_masks, color_list, default="white"):
  cond_bg_style = [f'background-color: {color}' for color in color_list]
  default_bg_style = f'background-color:{default}'
  a =  np.select(bool_masks, cond_bg_style, default=default_bg_style)
  print(a)
  return a
```

ahora bien, para esto requiero una mascara booleana para el np.select y la saco de la siguiente manera:

```
mask=[(dfs.iloc[x,26]=="NO") and (dfs.iloc[x,4] in listaCiudades) for x in range(len(dfs))]
```

color=["red"]

el for lo utilizo para recorrer el dfs y mirar si cada algun registro tiene en la columna 4 algunas de las ciudades que esta en un objeto tipo lista

```
(dfs.iloc[x,4] in listaCiudades) for x in range(len(dfs))
```

Y lo mismo hago con la otra parte de la condición

```
 (dfs.iloc[x,26]=="NO")
```

Todo esto es la mascara booleana que vienen a ser las condiciones para agregar color una casilla en especifico si el registro cumple todas las condiciones.

```
styled=dfs.style.apply(funciomAgregarColores,subset=["Zona de dificil Acceso"],bool_masks=mask,color_list=color)
```

Pero cuando ejecuto me sale un error

```
    Input In [249], in funciomAgregarColores(column, bool_masks, color_list, default)
      2 cond_bg_style = [f'background-color: {color}' for color in color_list]
      3 default_bg_style = f'background-color:{default}'
----> 4 a =  np.select(bool_masks, cond_bg_style, default=default_bg_style)
      5 print(a)
      6 return a

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in select(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:666, in select(condlist, choicelist, default)
    664 # Check the size of condlist and choicelist are the same, or abort.
    665 if len(condlist) != len(choicelist):
--> 666     raise ValueError(
    667         'list of cases must be same length as list of conditions')
    669 # Now that the dtype is known, handle the deprecated select([], []) case
    670 if len(condlist) == 0:

ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions
```

Cuando lo hago con una sola condición por ejemplo

```
mask=[dfs["Zona de dificil Acceso"]=="NO"]
```

Me funciona y cuando reviso el tamaño del objeto utilizo len(mask) y es 1 pero cuando lo hago con la condicion real me dice que tiene un tamaño de 2620 que es el tamaño de dfs. No se que error estoy cometiendo y seguire intentando. Necesito un poco de ayuda.

Comment: Podrias agregar tu *DataFrame* y decir cual es la condición en base al df que agregas ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Jred0n29 Gracias por comentar! Subí un nuevo post respecto a esto que esta mejor explicado y con las lineas de codigo
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547945/agregar-color-a-una-celda-de-un-dataframe-si-cumplen-varias-condiciones